# react-three/fiber detect click on empty area

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

Im wondering how to detect a click on an empty space on my canvas using react-three/fiber. For example to deselect an object. Is there a build in way or do I have to implement a raycaster?

thanks in regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `onPointerMissed` on the `<Canvas>` element, as documented here: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/events

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats exactly what I was looking for

Comment: The link is broke

Comment: The casing in docs changed, fixed it... @Blunderchips